# ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard polyfills library for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, polyfills, ecmascript-6

I have looked for `isInteger` test to validate form field value including SO with tricks, like:

```
num === parseInt(num)
```

I found page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger that provide polyfill for this function (it included in EC6 spec):

```
Number.isInteger = Number.isInteger || function(value) {
    return typeof value === "number" && 
       isFinite(value) && 
       Math.floor(value) === value;
};
```

This is not only first JS polyfill that I see on MDN.

Are there any community supported library that incorporate and support JS polyfills for modern JS standards?

I found `es6.js` in `webshim` project:

```
bash# git clone https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim.git
bash# cd webshim

bash# grep -R isInteger
dev/shims/es6.js:761:  isInteger: function(value) {
dev/shims/es6.js:767:  return Number.isInteger(value) && Math.abs(value) <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

but I afraid that this library over-complicated (may negatively effect to already used jQuery/Bootstrap/etc code) and not sure how this project itself healthy  (there are many commiters, but also there are many open bugs).

Note that `polyfill` word I have learned 5 minute ago from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill. That is why question may look dumb for veteran JS wizards.

Comment: Questions asking to find a third party library are considered "off topic" for Stack Overflow.  There are several ES6 polyfill projects which a google search should help you find.  Not everything in ES6 can be done with a polyfill.  Once you find a library and you have a specific question about that library that you could not find an answer to with your own research, you could ask that type of question here.

Comment: Ok, fill free to close. +1

Comment: You can remove the question yourself if you want.

Comment: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js

Comment: First google result: https://github.com/es-shims

Comment: Also, Modernizr maintains an extensive list: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#ecmascript-6-harmony

Comment: Hi closer men! May you just move question to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ (I have googled it this morning)? Sorry for long response I fell sleep in deep night (((

Answer (score -1):

Have you heard of Babel?  If you're into es6 then you should definitely go look up Babel.

Essentially Babel transpiles your es6 code to es5 so that it can be used by older browsers. Babel is extremely popular and is supported by people who work at Facebook.

Babel also provides a polyfill https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/ that you can get by doing an npm install babel and finding the polyfill in the folder.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be closed.  Please don't support off-topic questions by providing answers to them.

Comment: Thanks, never have heart about this project. Thanks for interest to question.